# How to make installation disk/pendrive of Mountain Lion in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, macos, install

I would like to install Mac OS Mountain Lion in my Intel Core i3 processor.

I have:

1. a Mac OS .DMG file
2. Windows 7 OS

Is it possible to make installation disk of Mac OS in Windows 7

Comment: Last I knew (but commenting instead of answering since I haven't ever tried) Windows 7 cannot read DMGs, nor HFS partitions. As far as I'm aware, this is not possible to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use [transmac](http://www.asy.com/scrtm.htm) to open the .dmg install file and open the "shared support" folder contained inside. Find the file labeled "installESD.img" and burn it to your pen drive in the format "MAC OS Extended (Journaled)"

Voila, bootable pen drive.

Answer (score 1):

it's already answered on SuperUser. You can use Transmac according to this.

[SuperUser: Create a bootable USB drive from a DMG file on Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/383235/create-a-bootable-usb-drive-from-a-dmg-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a program called [Win32DiskImager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/files/latest/download), that can take the `.dmg` file and your flash drive and make it bootable. I just used it today and got OS X working on my desktop with Windows.